# How to access dynamic variable names in twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have some variables in twig like

```
placeholder1
placeholder2
placeholderx
```

To call them, I am looping through the array of objects "invoices"

```
{% for invoices as invoice %}
    need to display here the placeholder followed by the invoice id number
    {{ placeholedr1 }}
```

Comment: where do you define placeholder 1 - x? Are they global accessable does every invoice got his own placeholder?

Comment: I am defining them in the controler and passing them to the twig template.

Comment: Can you show me the code where you're defining and passing them? Then i should be able to help you :)

Comment: Could you not set create an array of the placeholders and call them like `{{ placeholder[invoice.id] }}`, or, alternatively, generate the placeholder in a service and then call it in a TwigExtensions using your invoice or invoice.id?

Comment: Thanks you all, but as a workarround, I created a new method in my Invoice entity where I am setting up the Placeholder.

Answer (score 32):

Instead of using the [`attribute` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html), you can also access values of the `_context` array with the regular bracket notation:

```
{{ _context['placeholder' ~ id] }}
```

I would personally use this one as it's more concise and in my opinion clearer.

If the [environment option](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#environment-options) `strict_variables` is set to `true`, you should also use the `default` filter:

```
{{ _context['placeholder' ~ id]|default }}

{{ attribute(_context, 'placeholder' ~ id)|default }}
```

Otherwise you'll get a `Twig_Error_Runtime` exception if the variable doesn't exist. For example, if you have variables `foo` and `bar` but try to output the variable `baz` (which doesn't exist), you get that exception with the message `Key "baz" for array with keys "foo, bar" does not exist`.

A more verbose way to check the existence of a variable is to use the [`defined` test](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/defined.html):

```
{% if _context['placeholder' ~ id] is defined %} ... {% endif %}
```

With the `default` filter you can also provide a default value, e.g. `null` or a string:

```
{{ _context['placeholder' ~ id]|default(null) }}

{{ attribute(_context, 'placeholder' ~ id)|default('Default value') }}
```

If you omit the default value (i.e. you use `|default` instead of `|default(somevalue)`), the default value will be an empty string.

`strict_variables` is `false` by default, but I prefer to set it to `true` to avoid accidental problems caused by e.g. typos.

Answer (score 31):

I just had the same issue - and using this first answer and after some additional research found the `{{ attribute(_context, 'placeholder'~invoice.id) }}` should work (`_context` being the global context object containing all objects by name)

Comment: It seems if you use `_context` in the `macro`, it will see only the vars which are defined in `macro` scope, but doesn't see global vars.

Answer (score 10):

I guess you could use the Twig `attribute` function.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/attribute.html

Comment: Thanks, I sow that but how can this apply to my example?

Comment: Does this work?

{{ attribute(app, 'placeholder'~invoice.id) }}

Comment: No, it tells me that the global variable placeholdersxx does not exists.

Answer (score 4):

My solution for this problem:

Create array of placeholder(x). Like:

```
# Options
$placeholders = array(
    'placeholder1' => 'A',
    'placeholder2' => 'B',
    'placeholder3' => 'C',
);

# Send to View ID invoice
$id_placeholder = 2;
```

Send both variables for view and in your template call:

```
{{ placeholders["placeholder" ~ id_placeholder ] }}
```

This print "B".

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
attribute(_context, 'placeholder'~invoice.id)
```