# Variables concatenation

Tags: twig

After about an year of using Smarty i wanted to try Twig.
I am facing a problem concatenating a string and a variable to build dynamically the titles of the page when i switch the language.

In Smarty, the controller passes to the template the variables:
`$title_it` and `$title_en`
For the title of the page i do `<title>{$title_{$lang}}</title>` (where `$lang` is a global variable) and i can switch the values of the variables when i change the language.
I am not able to replicate this behaviour in Twig.
I tried the following methods without having success:

`{{ title_ ~ {{ lang }} }}` (I think Twig sees the variable "title_" doesn't exists.

`'title_'~{{ lang }}` (This prints 'title_it' and not it's content)

Is there a way to keep this logic and continuing to use this approach or do i have to handle the titles of the pages differenly?

Thanks a lot,

Manuel

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but it seems like it would be cleaner to define `$title['it']` and `$title['en']` instead of using dynamic variable names.

Comment: You are over thinking this.   {{title}}_{{lang}} is all you really need.  But take a look at the translation component: http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - How to access dynamic variable names in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/symfony2-how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_context` variable holds all variables in the current context, so you can do:

```
{{ _context['title_' ~ lang]|default }}
```

This is basically the same as using the [`attribute` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html):

```
{{ attribute(_context, 'title_' ~ lang)|default }}
```

I would personally use the former as it's more concise and in my opinion clearer.

The [`default` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html) is needed when the [environment option](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#environment-options) `strict_variables` is set to `true` (the default value is `false`, but I prefer to set it to `true` to avoid accidental problems caused by e.g. typos), otherwise you'll get a `Twig_Error_Runtime` exception if the variable doesn't exist. For example, if you have variables `title_en` and `title_it` but try to output the variable `title_de` (which doesn't exist), you get that exception with the message `Key "title_de" for array with keys "title_en, title_it, lang" does not exist`.

A more verbose way to check the existence of a variable is to use the [`defined` test](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#environment-options):

```
{% if _context['title_' ~ lang] is defined %} ... {% endif %}
```

With the `default` filter  you can also provide a default value:

```
{{ _context['title_' ~ lang]|default('Default title') }}
```

If you omit the default value (i.e. you do `|default` instead of `|default('some value')`), the default value will be an empty string.

[See TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/9d5zqs)

Comment: Thanks for this well explained answer! This is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think here the solutions which can fix your problems.

Controller code:

```
 return $this->render('myTwig.html.twig', array(
            'lang'=>'en',
            'title_en'=>'English Title',
            'title_it'=>'Italian Title'
        ));
```

Twig Code:

```
{% set myVar='title_'~lang  %}
{{ attribute(_context, myVar) }}
```

This will display "English Title" on your page.
Here  `_context` variable is a magic variable in twig where you can find all parameters which you passed from your controller to this twig.

```
attribute(_context,myVar)
```

it displays the value from passed parameters key to value.

Hope this will solve your problems.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I would change the controller to pre-calculate the language dependent value for `title` before passing it to the twig template.  If you are unable (unwilling) to do that, then ...

```
<title>{% if lang == 'it' %}{{ title_it }}{% else %}{{ title_en }}{% endif %}</title>
```