# Access variable inside a loop and variable in Twig

Tags: twig

I would like to do the following:

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
    {% if content_{{ i }}_raw == 2 %} 
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible to get `{{ i }}` inside the variable `content_1_raw` and replace the `1` with the value of `i`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The `_context` variable holds all variables in the current context. You can access its values with the bracket notation or using the [`attribute` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html):

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
    {% if _context['content_' ~ i ~ '_raw'] == 2 %} 
        ...
    {% endif %}

    {# or #}

    {% if attribute(_context, 'content_' ~ i ~ '_raw') == 2 %} 
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have written more details about this here: [Symfony2 - How to access dynamic variable names in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/symfony2-how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig/48543281#48543281)

Also, instead of writing `'content_' ~ i ~ '_raw'` (tilde, `~`, is [string concatenation operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators)), you can also use [string interpolation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#string-interpolation):

```
"content_#{i}_raw"
```