# Replace dynamic variable in for loop

Tags: twig

I'm trying to figure out how I can retrieve the count and replace the "0" in the loop below

```
{% for product in products %}

  {{ loop.index0 }} <--- This count too replace "0" designer.0.images
  
  {% for key,value in designer.0.images %}
     <div class="imageprodalign">{{ value }}<br>{{ key }}</div>              
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access variable inside a loop and variable in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48752840/access-variable-inside-a-loop-and-variable-in-twig)

Comment: No ... as I'm trying to get the loop.index0 value to replace .0. in the second for. But thanks for the link ... always learning new things

Comment: ... As seen in the linked question use either `designer[loop.index0].images` or `attribute(designer, loop.index0).images`

Comment: Ah ! ... Nice thanks. That works ... new to twig ...