# How to combining a variable in twig

Tags: php, twig

I'm a newbie at twig and I had a code below which i need to change to twig code but still can't get what i want

```
<?php echo ${'jne_reguler_' . $geo_zone['geo_zone_id'] . '_rate'}; ?>
```

I really have no idea how the code replaced in twig syntax

Comment: so you need to output variable by dynamic name, right? if yes, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/symfony2-how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig

Comment: yes you're correct
i had trying to put {% if ({{ attribute(_context, 'jne_reguler_'~geo_zone['geo_zone_id']~'_status') }}) %} but still got error 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in "extension/shipping/jne_reguler.twig" at line 87.' in /home/marketplace/public_html/system/library/template/Twig/ExpressionParser.php:281 Stack trace: #0

Comment: Do the setup in the variable array you pass to the render call, or create a twig function where you pass in the zone id and get back the (possible also given) rate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this one

```
<textarea name="jne_reguler_{{ geo_zone['geo_zone_id'] }}_rate" rows="5" placeholder="{{ entry_rate }}" id="input-rate{{ geo_zone['geo_zone_id'] }}" class="form-control">{{ attribute(_context, 'jne_reguler_'~geo_zone['geo_zone_id']~'_rate') }}</textarea>
```

and this one

```
{% if attribute(_context, 'jne_reguler_'~geo_zone['geo_zone_id']~'_status') %}
```

so far no error given

thank you to all of you that have answered my question specially for @skyboyer that give me the clue

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any concatenate operator in twig, instead:

`jne_reguler_{{ geo_zone.geo_zone_id }}_rate`

Comment: i had trying that one but throwing me an error
i had use like this {{ jne_reguler_{{ geo_zone.geo_zone_id }}_rate }}

Comment: @NicolasSetiono ``{{ }}`` is a signal to print variable, you need to remove those double bracket in both ends

Comment: really appreciate your explanation bro :)