# Opencart php to twig

Tags: twig, opencart-3

can anybody help  convert to twig this piece of code.

```
foreach ($methods as $method){?>
        <li><a href="#tab-express<?php echo $method;?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo ${'tab_express' . $method}; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
```

I have tried this:

```
{% for method in methods %}     <li><a href="#tab-express{{ method }}" data-toggle="tab">{{ 'tab_express' ~ method }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
```

But this part: `{{ 'tab_express' ~ method }}` does not work.      What wrong?

*EDIT:
 need retrieve  names of the tabs from  the controller

```
foreach ($data['methods'] as $method){  
        $data['tab_express' . $method] = $this->language->get('tab_express' . $method);
}
```

*
I answered below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - How to access dynamic variable names in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/symfony2-how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

Answer (score 0):

solution for my question i found.
in controller should be:

```
foreach ($data['methods'] as $method){  
        $data['tab_express'][$method] = $this->language->get('tab_express' . $method);
```

Twig:

```
{% for method in methods %}     
<li><a href="#tab-express{{ method }}" data-toggle="tab">{{ tab_express[method] }}</a> </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller it should be:

```
{{ attribute(_context, 'tab_express' ~ method) }}
```