# Twig for loop array key

Tags: twig

I'm new to twig, facing some issue on for loop.
    For loop how to get key

```
{% set data = {pounds: {all: {year: {2012: 123,2013:234,2014:500}}}} %}
{% set i = {0:2012,1:2013,2:2014} %}
{% for years,value in data.millions.all %}
  {% for key,val in i %}
   {{ value.val }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

After execute i got below error

```
#1    Type    Twig_Error_Runtime
#2    Message    Key "val" for array with keys "2012, 2013, 2014" does not exist.
#3    At    twigfiddle:environment/KGoFPP6aiGA8cNzG/twig/main.twig:5
```

Expected output

```
123
234
500
```

Ref : https://twigfiddle.com/1c6rsv

Help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - How to access dynamic variable names in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/symfony2-how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

Comment: try {{ value[val] }}