# How to access an element with an unknow name

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I need to show a value from an element but his name is not always the same.
In my "competence" object, I have 4 fields, let's say `field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4`, but in function of an other value, I only have to display on of them.
I have the value in an other field of my "competence" object, "field_niveau_attendu" (it is set to 1, 2, 3 or 4)

I tried to use a "set" function

```
{% set niveau = "field_descriptif_" ~ competence.field_niveau_attendu.value %}
<p class="">{{ competence.field_competences_transverses.entity.niveau.value }}</p>
```

but it won't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - How to access dynamic variable names in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/symfony2-how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

Answer (score -1):

if in field_competences_transverses you have only 4 fields (field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4) you can try to use "for"

```
{% if competence.field_niveau_attendu.value is defined %}
    {% set niveau = competence.field_niveau_attendu.value %}
    {% for descriptif in competence.field_competences_transverses.entity %}
        {% if loop.index == niveau %}
            {{ descriptif.value }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: twig can't loop object properties by default