# Create multiple arrays in Twig and access them through separate expressions

Tags: php, data-structures, twig

I have 20 groups of 4 numbers each. Each element of the array must be displayed separately but in the right sequence in different locations (divs), but which group is displayed must be selected randomly.

If on load, group A is selected at random through Twig, all elements of Group will be placed in 4 different divs on the page.
In the example bellow the numbers are A1, A2 etc for clarity but the goal is to include numbers chosen arbitrarily (there is no logic or system on the sequence, so I cannot generate it, but it must be kept).

This is my structure so far:

```
    {% set array = {
      'A': {
        1 : 'A1',
        2 : 'A2',
        3 : 'A3',
        4 : 'A4',
      },
        'B': {
        1 : 'B1',
        2 : 'B2',
        3 : 'B3',
        4 : 'B4',
      },

       'C': {
        1 : 'C1',
        2 : 'C2',
        3 : 'C3',
        4 : 'C4',
      },
    }
%}

{% set randomGroup = random('ABC') %}

 {{ array.randomGroup.1 }}
 {{ array.randomGroup.2 }}
 {{ array.randomGroup.3 }}
 {{ array.randomGroup.4 }}
```

This would be ideal, as I could place each element separately wherever I want. However 'randomGroup' inside the expression does not work (shows nothing, also on print_r ). I can only seem to access {{ randomGroup }} as a expression on its own. Is this incorrect Twig practice, or something else that is wrong with this code/structure?

I've also tried doing a for loop but the closest I could get was to get the first value of each group, which would not fit the structure that seems most suitable for this.

```
{% for group in array %}
    {{ group.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

This prints

> A1 B1 C1

This is a Twig issue as well as an attempt to find a suitable data structure for this issue.
Is there a more efficient way to create groups of numbers with a fixed sequence that can be used as separate expressions?

Comment: You might want to use the array notation `array[randomGroup]` or the `attribute` function `attribute(array, randomGroup)[1]`. See [How to access dynamic variable names in twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

Comment: @DarkBee This is exactly it, thank you!