# WordPress - How to concatenate variable with Timber (TWIG) in a loop

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I use Timber (TWIG) with WordPress.

I'm trying to create a tab system with two differents list of posts. I'm trying to get the number of post for each list (custom post type video and custom post type podcast).

Example : videos **(3)** / podcasts **(12)**

I created a loop to get a list of posts for each custom post type (video and podcast).

### category.php

```
    $object_category = get_queried_object();
    $current_category = $object_category->term_id;

    $posts_types_selected = array('videos', 'podcasts');
    $context['posts_types_selected'] = $posts_types_selected;
    
    foreach ($posts_types_selected as $post_type_selected) {
        $context['posts_'.$post_type_selected] = Timber::get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => array($post_type_selected),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'category__in' => array($current_category),
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'paged' => 1,
            'has_password' => FALSE
        ));
    }
```

### category.twig

```
<ul class="tab-menu">
    {% for item in posts_types_selected %}
        <li><a href="#" class="tab-control">{{ item }} ({{ 'posts_' ~ item|length }})</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I'm trying to have something like that for each `li`

```
<li><a href="#" class="tab-control">{{ item }} ({{ posts_videos|length }})</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="tab-control">{{ item }} ({{ posts_podcasts|length }})</a></li>
```

How to concatenate value in my array `$posts_types_selected` with `posts_`

### **UPDATE**

I tried solution here : [How to access dynamic variable names in twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

```
{% for item in posts_types_selected %}
<li><a href="#" class="tab-control">{{ item }} ({{ _context['posts_' ~ item] }})</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

But I got : `Notice: Array to string conversion`

I tried this too :

```
{% for item in posts_types_selected %}
<li><a href="#" class="tab-control">{{ item }} ({{ 'posts_' ~ item }})</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I got : `videos (posts_videos)` / `podacasts (posts_podcasts)`

But it's interpreted as strings and not as variables.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access dynamic variable names in twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

Comment: Thank you. I tried this solution but I got : Notice: Array To String Conversion. My case is different I use Timber

Comment: Doesn't matter if you use timber or not. Please update the question with the code u've tried

Comment: You still need to add your original filter `length` to it, e.g. `{{ _context['posts_' ~ item] | length }}`