# Twig use dynamic variables

Tags: variables, twig, timber, templating-engine

I want to display for each user their availability. Therefore I want to concatenate a {{variable}} into {{variable}} (example below).

I have an array of workdays:

```
$context['workdays'] = [ 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday' ];
```

And some database fields like `monday_morning_availability` and `tuesday_morning_availability` etc.

With `{{user.monday_morning_availability}}` I can display its availability for monday and `{{user.tuesday_morning_availability}}` for tuesday etc. However I don't want to repeat myself for each day to do this.

I want to call `{{ user.workday_morning_availability }}` to dynamically insert a variable into the call.

I've tried:

```
{% for user in users %}
{% for workday in workdays %}
    {{ workday}} : {{ attribute(_context, user.~'workday'~_morning_availability) }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But unfortunately that throws an error, see:

```
Uncaught Exception: Expected name or number
```

**Edit**:
I might be onto something..

```
    {% set foobar = workday ~ "_morning_availability" %}

    {{ foobar }}
    {{ workday }} : {{ attribute(_context, user.foobar) }}
```

Value of foobar is as expected: `monday_morning_availability`

This however doesn't work when called on the user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access dynamic variable names in twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

Comment: @DarkBee Nope, but I've found the solution; I've answered my own question :D

Comment: It's an exact duplicate, thats why i've casted the close-vote

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    {% set foobar = workday ~ "_morning_availability" %}

    {{ workday }} : {{ attribute(user, foobar) }}
```