# Concatenate in an element acf fields or an objects

Tags: object, twig, concatenation, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I'm trying to concatenate a Twig variable and an ACF options field but it doesn't work.

I have two footers and I want to select the correct one according to the correct page.

```
{% if post.slug == "page1" %}
    {% set pageType = "pages" %}
{% elseif post.slug == "page2" %}
    {% set pageType = "otherspages" %}
{% endif %}

<footer id="footer">
   <h2>{{ options.footer_~pageType~_titre }}</h2>
   <div>{{ options.footer_~pageType~_container }}<div>
</div>
```

The ACF fields are called footer_page_titre or footer_otherpage_titre depending on the footer I want to display

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access dynamic variable names in twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

Answer (score 1):

Try constructing the field name first, for example with the twig format filter which formats a given string by replacing the placeholders, similar to sprintf, and then access the field value by in the options data array.

Construct the field name:

```
{% set footer_title = "footer_%s_title"|format(pageType) %}
```

Access the value by array key

```
<h2>{{ options[footer_title] }}</h2>
```