# cant get inside key of an array that is numbers

Tags: html, arrays, twig

I have an array that I use to create a table, however, I first need to identify the path.
my Array is saved in:

```
page.cart.lineitems.elements
```

this is the output if i dump it:
[image]

in these two keys are my table arrays but I can't get inside.
The keys are named after 2 items in a cart where I can identify which one I want to use, so I get the values from a key called:
[image]

im saving the value of "_key" here:

```
{% set articleKey = _key %}
```

so now I should be able to use the key name as such

```
page.cart.lineitems.elements.articleKey
```

instead of `page.cart.lineitems.elements.120ac316d177487fa879c51e02845135`

inside the **articleKey.extensions.TwpSortiment.data** is
[image]

so I wrote this code but it still doesn't go inside my "articleKey"

```
<div class="twp-sortiment-form">
        {% set articleKey = _key %}
        {% for key in page.cart.lineitems.elements.articleKey.extentions.TwpSortiment.data %}

        //my table code

        {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

whats is the issue? why can I not go inside the articleKey? I tried it even with writing the whole name but an error occurs:

> Unexpected token "name" of value "ac316d177487fa879c51e02845135" ("end of statement block" expected).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access dynamic variable names in twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fixed it by typing the path this way `page.cart.lineitems.elements[articleKey]`

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31256662)

Comment: @VarunMahajan How would this be "a new question"? This is the OP answering their own question. Although the answer is not very good, it is still an answer to their question.

Comment: lol, basically someone could have told me to not use the dot . after 'elements' but becoz using dots is to go into an object but in my case i couldnt get into the key with a dot, so i  had to use elements[savedKeyName] or elements["the actual name of the key"]

Comment: I did tell, hence the fact that I voted to close this as [an exact duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)