# Twig print values and strings in set statements

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-webform

This twig template is not DRY.

```
{% set reviewer_0 = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:0:entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
{% set reviewer_1 = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:1:entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
{% set reviewer_2 = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:2:entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
{% if reviewer_0|length %}{{ reviewer_0 }}{% else %}{% endif %}
{% if reviewer_1|length %},{{ reviewer_1 }}{% else %}{% endif %}
{% if reviewer_2|length %},{{ reviewer_2 }}{% else %}{% endif %}
```

I tried using the example from twig documentation

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
    * {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

like this:

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
    {% set reviewer_{{ i }} = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:'{{ i }}':entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
    {% if reviewer_{{ i }}|length %}{{ reviewer_{{ i }} }}{% else %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't work. I think the strings have to be concatenated somehow. How do I create this loop in twig?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access dynamic variable names in twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `{% %}` you **can't** use `{{ }}` too.

First, you need to update

```
webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:'{{ i }}':entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options)

into

webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:' ~ i ~ ':entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options)
```

and variable name seems not correct too, you can just remove `_{{ i }}` part. Each turn it will overridden anyway.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks @Emircan ERKUL. Unfortunately,

`{% for i in 0..10 %}
    {{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:' ~ i ~ ':entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) }}
{% endfor %}`

generates `Twig syntax error: Unknown "webform_token" function in "index.html.twig" at line 2.`

Comment: The webform knows what a webform_token is, but `{% for i in 0..10 %}
{% set reviewer_~ i ~ = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:' ~ i ~ ':entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
{% endfor %}` throws `Unexpected token "operator" of value "~" ("end of statement block" expected) in "__string_template__4c27f4a5afa0845b24e961199f41e5bd" at line 2.`

Comment: "~" in the left side is not correct, do not use that. Are you sure that webform_token is available? First check with 

webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:0:entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options)

Also look; https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/300055

Answer (score 0):

I improved the twig based on @Emircan ERKUL's suggestion with the following:

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
{% if webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewers:' ~ i ~ ':entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options)|length %}
{% set reviewers = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewers:' ~ i ~ ':entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
{{ reviewers }},
{% else %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The comma at the end of `{{ reviewers }},` is not good and results in storing reviewers like this:

```
email1@emal.com,email2@email.com,email3@email.com,
```

The trailing comma is trimmed off somewhere else and `email3@mail.com,` is sent as `email3@mail.com`. I wouldn't mind improving the twig using a filter like the `join` filter except `reviewers` is not an array.

In any case, the element now offers up to 11 reviewers using DRY code and an simple mechanism for adding more.

If you want to use this pattern in a Drupal webform computed twig element, here's the entire element.

```
reviewer_mail:
    '#type': webform_computed_twig
    '#title': 'Reviewer mail'
    '#template': |-
        {% for i in 0..10 %}
        {% if webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewers:' ~ i ~ ':entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options)|length %}
        {% set reviewers = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewers:' ~ i ~ ':entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
        {{ reviewers }},
        {% else %}{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    '#whitespace': spaceless
    '#store': true
    '#ajax': true
```

`reviewers` in `webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewers:'` is another element, an Entity Select element, multiple true, target_type user, filter type role.